# Classify, up to similarity, real matrices of dimension $6\times6$ with minimal polynomial $(t-1)^2(t+1)(t-2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

**Classify, up to similarity, real matrices of dimension $6\times6$ with minimal polynomial $(t-1)^2(t+1)(t-2)$**

*My attempt:*

If the minimal polynomial is $(t-1)^2(t+1)(t-2)$ then we only have the following invariant factors:

$(t-1)^2(t+1)(t-2)=t^4-3t^3+t^2+3t-2, (t-1)^2=t^2-2t+1$

So, every matrix of dimension $6\times6$  with minimal polynomial $(t-1)^2(t+1)(t-2)$ is similar to

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$.

Is this reasoning correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand where the matrix $A$ is coming from? Also there are several possible matrices.

Comment: A is the rational form of a matrix having that minimal polynomial.

Comment: Have you seen Jordan form of a matrix ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Not yet, can we do an argument withput using that of that is neccesary?

Comment: Your claim about the rational form is incorrect. There are multiple rational forms with that minimal polynomial and you only found one. How do you know the dimension of the eigenspace of $2$ isn't greater than 1, for example? It's a possibility. The minimal polynomial does not tell you that, for example.

Comment: Have a look at this question and its answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4539912/305862) using Jordan Canonical Form (JCF)

Answer (score 1):

Assume that such a matrix is in Jordan canonical form. Only these blocks can appear along the diagonal of the matrix, because of the minimal polynomial being $m(t)=(t-1)^2(t+1)(t-2)$:
$$
      \begin{bmatrix}-1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2\end{bmatrix}. \tag{*}
$$
There can be multiple blocks of a given type, so long as they exactly fill the diagonal of the $6\times 6$ matrix, and so long as at least one of each of the following appears along the diagonal.
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}-1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Because the matrix is a $6\times 6$, that leaves the following possibilities for the remainder of the diagonal block matrices:
$$
     (a) [-1],[-1] \\
     (b) [-1],[1] \\
     (c) [-1],[2] \\
     (d) [1],[2] \\
     (e) [2],[2] \\
     (f) \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
So it seems to me that the set of all matrices with the given minimal polynomial are equivalent to a Jordan canonical form that has one of $6$ possible standard forms.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The matrices having the desired minimal polynomial, are similar to the ones having for only non zero elements the elements $2,-1,1$ or $B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ on the diagonal, with at least one $2$, one $-1$ and one $B$ on the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

It will be simpler to consider $3 \times 3$ block matrices.

In the spirit of the answer of Masacroso [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4540022/305862), here is "prototypical case" helping (so I think) to understand what is going on is as follows:

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
B & 0 & 0\\
0 & B & 0 \\
0 & 0 & D 
\end{bmatrix} \ \text{where} \ B:=\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{1} & 1\\
0 & \color{red}{1}
\end{bmatrix}, \ D:=\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{-1} & 0\\
0 & \color{red}{2}
\end{bmatrix}$$

(eigenvalues have been written in red in order to spot their placement ; please note in particular the typical Jordan block $B$).

Let us now consider decomposition :

$$M=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
B & 0 & 0\\
0 & B & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}}_P+\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & D 
\end{bmatrix}}_Q$$

We have, separately, $(P-I_6)^2=0$ (but not  $(P-I_6)^1=0$) and $(Q+I_6)*(Q-2*I_6)=0$.

Therefore:

$$(M-I_6)^2*(M+I_6)*(M-2*I_6)=0$$

giving the expression of the minimal polynomial.